# CHKDSK always runs on Hyper-V image

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I am having a problem with one of my VM's.  Every time it boots, CHKDSK runs and finds no errors, but it goes into an endless loop (CHKDSK/Reboot/CHKDSK).

The only way I can get Windows to boot is by cancelling the chkdsk.

Is there any way I can tell windows to not do it?  What do you guys suggest? Can't redo server.

I guess it's also fair to say I get the following errors in Event Viewer

"The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable.  Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume \Device\HarddiskVolume2"

"The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable.  Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume C:\"

I only have 1 VHD attached, not sure what Volume 2 is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the link below to disable automatic chkdsk on startup:[Disable Automatic chkdsk on startup](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-disable-the-chkdsk-check-disk-on-start-up/35f58c69-7a6c-4e1b-aec3-26d7131ec643)

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Drive is still dirty, but chkdsk never finds anything so I am fine with this.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown the VM, attach the disk on the Hypervisor (start `diskmgmt.msc` → Action → Attach VHD). Run `chkdsk X: /b /f /r` on all volumes on that disk (replace `X:` with the actual drive letter to which the volume is mapped). Detach the disk again and boot the VM.

Comment: Little confused here.  The disk is attached to the Hyper-V VM already.

Comment: You can attach the VHD like a physical disk in `diskmgmt` of the host operating system. It's similar to attaching a physical disk from one computer to another computer for troubleshooting.